# Create table : Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'wp_gom_my_project' (
'my_project_id' int NOT NULL auto_increment,
'my_project_name' text NOT NULL ,
'user_id' int NOT NULL ,
'my_project_description' text NOT NULL ,
'my_project_deadline' datetime NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`my_project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I just can't find the error.

This is the error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_gom_my_project' ( 'my_project_id' int NOT NULL auto_increment, 'my_project' at line 1
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f2a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong kind of quotes:

- ' is for quoting strings
- ` is for quoting identifiers (table names, column names, etc)

Since none of your table or column names would be a keyword anyway, just don't put any quotes at all, and it will look much nicer. :)

Comment: Thank you, you saved 1 hour of my life!

Answer (score 1):

Dont put any quotes, use **`**

Try this one

Here is [reference fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d202d) or [another one with `](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f2a)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_gom_my_project (
my_project_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
my_project_name text NOT NULL ,
user_id int NOT NULL ,
my_project_description text NOT NULL ,
my_project_deadline datetime NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`my_project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Or replace `'` with **`**

Comment: @MaartenSchermer: You should accept this one (or any correct answer for that matter), then :)

Answer (score 0):

Table name and other fields should not be quoted.

Try

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_gom_my_project (
my_project_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
my_project_name text NOT NULL ,
user_id int NOT NULL ,
my_project_description text NOT NULL ,
my_project_deadline datetime NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`my_project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Table name and column names should not be enclosed with single or double quotes. you can use backticks `

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes denote a string value in MySQL. If you want to quote table names, you have to use a backtick:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_gom_my_project` (
  `my_project_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `my_project_name` text NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL ,
  `my_project_description` text NOT NULL ,
  `my_project_deadline` datetime NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`my_project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `` `(back quote) `` instead of `'(apostrophe)` when difining column and table names